# Shopify Remote add to cart - Same variant id, different properties but yet the Shopify cart considers them the same

Tags: shopping-cart, shopify

I am using the Shopify remote add to cart form to pass a group of customized products.  Same Shopify product (variant-id), different custom designs (line item properties).
The form call treats the 3 customized products that I am adding to the cart as identical even though they have distinct line items.  If I push this to the Shopify cart I will see a product with a quantity of 3.  If I submit a form for each product individually then it treats them as unique products in the cart which is the behavior I would hope for.
Here is and example of the code I am trying to use (Notice the "Customizer#" and "Your Design" is unique for each product):

```
<form action="http://www.boardlams.com/cart/add" method="post"> 

  <input name="id[]" value="262542038" type="hidden">
  <input id="Customizer#" name="properties[Customizer#]" value="RTD-Design-1" type="hidden">
  <input id="YourDesign" name="properties[YourDesign]"   value="http://designer.realtimedesigner.com/orders2/153000/153500/153561/3/design_1.png?1355818798" type="hidden">
  <input name="id[]" value="262542038" type="hidden">
  <input id="Customizer#" name="properties[Customizer#]" value="RTD-Design-2" type="hidden">
  <input id="YourDesign" name="properties[YourDesign]" value="http://designer.realtimedesigner.com/orders2/153000/153500/153561/3/design_2.png?1355818798" type="hidden">
  <input name="id[]" value="262542038" type="hidden">
  <input id="Customizer#" name="properties[Customizer#]" value="RTD-Design-3" type="hidden">
  <input id="YourDesign" name="properties[YourDesign]" value="http://designer.realtimedesigner.com/orders2/153000/153500/153561/3/design_3.png?1355818798" type="hidden">
  <input name="return_to" value="/cart" type="hidden">
  <input value="Many Customized Products" type="submit">

</form>
```

Is there a way to have the Shopify cart consider each product as separate item in the cart when submitting the form this way?  Sending a remote add to cart form per customized project is not a good solution in this case because we want to submit all of the products as a group.
I appreciate any insights!
Regards,
John

Comment: Why so many `<input name="id[]" value="262542038" type="hidden">`?